# Turn SVG icon into button

Tags: svg

```
<button className="zapButton"> <Zap /> </button>
```

The only thing I've been able to find is wrapping the icon in the button tag. The only problem with this is I get a rectangular button and the icon inside the rectangle. What i am trying to figure out is how to make it so that the button is only the SVG icon.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `onClick` attribute to `Zap` itself, any element can be clickable, doesn't need to be button.
Or you can remove the border from the button you currently have with css `border: none` to make it look like there's no rectangular button.

Answer (score -2):

```
<button class="zap-button" style="height: auto; width: auto; border: none;">
  <svg></svg>
</button>
```

And of course you shouldn't use inline styles.